# Jenkins not detecting python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed python plugin.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Python+Plugin

But when running a test job, I am getting below error as python not found.

```
Started by user uday kiran
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testpy
[testpy] $ python C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson2789497398258110842.py
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testpy"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
```

[image]

Any suggestion?
Even I tried keeping only the folder,instead of path to exe, still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seems like a Python issue.
The error says it cannot find the actual file eg. **testpy**

Make sure your path is correct as well as the file you trying to reference eg.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testpy.py

Comment: testpy is the job name.THe folder exists already.The python file generated by jenkins is hudson2789497398258110842.py. It is beiing crreated also by it.